# How to generate CSV file under 3 MB

Tags: php

i've been wondering how to generate a CSV file from array and keep it under certain size. Can someone show me how to do it?

```
do
    {      
        $fp = fopen($file, 'a');  
            
        fputcsv($fp, generateArray(30));  

        fclose($fp);
        $filesize = round(filesize($file) / 1024 / 1024, 2); // megabytes with 2 digit
    
        echo "Chars.csv ".$filesize ;

    }while($filesize < 1); //in MB
```

Comment: Do you mean at the moment the file is over the size you need.  Do you want to split the data into separate files if it's larger?

Comment: Well for starters, the return value of `fputcsv` in the success case, _is_ the length of the string that was written already - so you could simply sum those up, instead of constantly opening the file, writing, closing it, and determining the current file size (which probably would not even work the way you currently have it, because the result of `filesize` calls gets cached - you'd need to involve `clearstatcache` here to begin with, for that to give current results.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you for your attention. clearstatcache() solved the issue

```
do
    {      
        fputcsv($fp, generateArray(30));  
        
        $filesize = round(filesize($file) / 1024 / 1024, 2); // megabytes with 2 digit
    
        clearstatcache();

    }while($filesize < 3); //in MB
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't practical to use the printable size for calculations. Plus you don't need to ask the filesystem for information you're generating yourself. Putting that together:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');
$filesize = 0;
do {
    $filesize += fputcsv($fp, generateArray(30));
    echo $file, ' ', round($filesize / 1024 / 1024, 2), "MB\n";
} while ($filesize < 1048576); // 1 MB
fclose($fp);
```

We are, however, missing a detail. We check size *after* writing, thus we'll always overflow the limit. If this is important, we can't really use `fputcsv()`. We need an alternative mechanism were we can generate a line in advance and then decide if it'll get included. It isn't too difficult to generate CSV manually, but I can also think of having a secondary stream like `fopen('php://memory', 'w');` to insert individual lines for size checks only and get it removed afterwards.